# Regex for alphanumeric password, with at least 1 number and character

Tags: c#, javascript

Need help with a regex for alphanumeric password, with at least 1 number and character, and the length must be between 8-20 characters.

I have this but doesn't seem to be working (it doesn't have length requirements either):

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

Answer (score 10):

If you take a look at this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998267.aspx), it gives an example of a password validation RegEx expression, and (more specifically) how to use it in ASP.NET.

For what you're looking to accomplish, this should work:

```
    (?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20})$
```

This requires at least one digit, at least one alphabetic character, no special characters, and from 8-20 characters in length.

Comment: To clarify, the first "negative lookahead assertion", i.e. the "(?!^[0-9]*$)", is responsible for ensuring there is at least one alphabetic character, the second is to ensure there is at least one digit, and finally the "^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20})$" says we need 8-20 alpha numerics.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a handful of simple functions to check?

```
checkPasswordLength( String password);
checkPasswordNumber( String password);
```

Maybe a few more to check for occurrences of the same character repeatedly and consecutively.

Comment: Input validation is something that regex is great for, and using a RegEx expression gives you more flexibility in the future.

Comment: They're not "great" for it when you have do non-matching lookaheads and the like. If you do use regex, there's no reason to shoehorn everything into a single regex. +1 for a sane answer.

Comment: @Adam Robinson - who says checkPasswordLength() can't use a RegEx within the function? Nothing's stopping you from using their advantages in this solution.

Comment: @ceeja, @John: The flexability and speed of RegEx comes largely from being able to check things (at least from a development perspective) in a single pass. Breaking it up into two statements either explicitly or via encapsulation in multiple functions, will lessen it. It also seems to be overengineered for something so simple. I fail to see how using a regex to validate input is "insane".

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=.{8,20}$)(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*
```

? :)

Comment: It seems like the .* at the end will match even special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to do this validation with some simple string functions instead of trying to shoehorn a difficult to validate regex into doing this?

Comment: Meh, sometimes Regex'es are easier for this kind of (Password?)-validation. Especially since you can use the Asp.Net regex-validators :)

Comment: Sanjay, input validation is one of the most frequent applications of RegEx, and using them gives you more flexibility if/when the validation requirements change.

Comment: Regex validation doesn't tell you what's wrong with failing input, other than "this didn't match the regex," so you can't tell the user specifically what he did wrong.  Which, in a lot of circumstances, is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will be closer to your needs.  (I didn't test it, though.)

```
Regex test = new Regex("^(?:(?<ch>[A-Za-z])|(?<num>[9-0])){8,20}$");
Match m = test.Match(input);
if (m.Success && m.Groups["ch"].Captures.Count > 1 && m.Groups["num"].Captures.Count > 1)
{
  // It's a good password.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is for javascript

```
// *********** ALPHA-Numeric check ***************************
function checkAlphaNumeric(val)
{
    var mystring=new String(val)

    if(mystring.search(/[0-9]+/)==-1) // Check at-leat one number
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(mystring.search(/[A-Z]+/)==-1 && mystring.search(/[a-z]+/)==-1) // Check at-leat one character
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```