# Regular Expression For Password in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, regex, passwords

I am pretty much weak in creating Regular Expression. So I am here.

I need a regular expression satisfying the following.

1. Atleast one numeric value and Atleast one alphabet should be present for the password
2. Minimum 6 Maximum 32 characters should be allowed.

Comment: Why do you need to use regex for validation of the password? Some simple Javascript/Objective-C code should be able to enforce the password requirements.

Comment: I Use Validation Class.. i pretty much validate every textfield using Regular Expressions. I find it very easy for Validations. Only thing i have to figure out is this regex. So here i am..

Comment: Please search SO first: such questions are asked on a daily basis. Perhaps not the exact requirements as yours, but easily changed to fit your needs.

Comment: @Bart: Hey this is a different regular expression i need.

Comment: Like I said, search a bit. Take a look at [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195665/regex-for-alphanumeric-password-with-at-least-1-number-and-character), it's pretty much just like yours.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
 -(BOOL) isPasswordValid:(NSString *)pwd {
     if ( [pwd length]<6 || [pwd length]>32 ) return NO;  // too long or too short
     NSRange rang;
     rang = [pwd rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]];
     if ( !rang.length ) return NO;  // no letter
     rang = [pwd rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];
     if ( !rang.length )  return NO;  // no number;
     return YES;
 }
```

This is clearly not a regex, but imo regex is overkill for this.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z]).{6,32}$
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using any third party libraries like Regexkit you can check for your requirements like so:

```
    if ([[password rangeOfCharacterFromSet: [ NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]] &&
         [password rangeOfCharacterFromSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"0123456789"]] && 
        (6 < [password length]) && [password length] < 32)) {
              NSLog(@"acceptable password");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2.pdf) you can find a usefull regexp cheatsheet wich also provide some examples.
One of these is really similar to your needs (the 6th in the "Sample pattern box) :)

Answer (score 1):

The following should meet the minimum/max characters, at least 1 alpha and 1 numeric character requirements:

```
^(?=.{6,32}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$
```