# C# Alphanumeric Password validation?

Tags: c#, regex

Can any one provide me regx validator which validate the following;

Password must be an alphanumeric password i.e. at least 1 number and at least 1 alphabet.

I tried the following, but it did not work.

```
(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9])$
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for alphanumeric password, with at least 1 number and character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195665/regex-for-alphanumeric-password-with-at-least-1-number-and-character)

Comment: so you want us to write your code for you?

Comment: @Muad'Dib: agreed! Smells like a homework question... This is my go-to source for regex building but you have to escape things differently w/ c#... http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: I have the code written already which is not working as expected.
this is my expression - (?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9])$

Comment: Please understand that all are not expert like you people and I hope this place is to helps people by sharing your ideas.

Comment: @Nilaa - It's not about being an expert. It's about showing that you tried. Your original question didn't include what you tried, even if it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, you just need to add a quantifier for your last expression and it will work fine. So, it should be something like this

`(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})$`.

Code will look like this

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})$");
boolean foundMatch = regexObj.IsMatch(passwordString);
```

You are currently matching a single digit or a letter as `[a-zA-Z0-9]` matches a single alphanum character. Read about character classes(`[]`) here http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html